# Email sending Android Studio

Tags: java, android, email, android-studio, jar

i'm trying to add sending email functionality to my android app. I have app which sends email written in eclipse, but I want to move my app to Android Studio. My code is same as in Eclipse, but when i want to send mail, my app stoped working. I'm using mail.jar, activation.jar and additional.jar for this.

Here is my code:

```
private void sendMail(String email, String subject, String messageBody)
{
    Session session = createSessionObject();
    try {
        Message message = createMessage(email, subject, messageBody, session);
        new SendMailTask().execute(message);
    } catch (AddressException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private Message createMessage(String email, String subject, String messageBody, Session session) throws MessagingException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from, senderName));
    message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(email, email));
    message.setSubject(subject);
    message.setText(messageBody);
    return message;
}

private Session createSessionObject() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

    return Session.getInstance(properties, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
        }
    });
}

private class SendMailTask extends AsyncTask<Message, Void, Void> {
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Please wait", "Sending mail", true, false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Message... messages) {
        try {
            Transport.send(messages[0]);
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I think that i get this error, because Android Studio cant see activation.jar and additional.jar files. My app stoped working when reached this line:

```
Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
```

How should I properly add these jar files to my Android Studio project?

EDIT:

I resolved this problem by adding lines to build.gradle:

```
compile files('libs/mail.jar')
compile files('libs/additionnal.jar')
compile files('libs/activation.jar')
```

But now i get errors in log cat when i click 'send email' button:

```
08-13 18:39:47.497 19034-20338/krzosik.mailsenderapp W/System.err: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
08-13 18:39:47.510 19034-20338/krzosik.mailsenderapp W/System.err:   nested exception is:
08-13 18:39:47.511 19034-20338/krzosik.mailsenderapp W/System.err:  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Connection closed by peer
08-13 18:39:47.512 19034-20338/krzosik.mailsenderapp W/System.err:     at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:1339)
08-13 18:39:47.513 19034-20338/krzosik.mailsenderapp W/System.err:     at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:420)
08-13 18:39:47.513 19034-20338/krzosik.mailsenderapp W/System.err:     at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:310)
08-13 18:39:47.513 19034-20338/krzosik.mailsenderapp W/System.err:     at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:169)
08-13 18:39:47.513 19034-20338/krzosik.mailsenderapp W/System.err:     at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:118)
08-13 18:39:47.514 19034-20338/krzosik.mailsenderapp W/System.err:     at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:188)
08-13 18:39:47.514 19034-20338/krzosik.mailsenderapp W/System.err:     at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:118)
08-13 18:39:47.514 19034-20338/krzosik.mailsenderapp W/System.err:     at krzosik.mailsenderapp.MainActivity$SendMailTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:100)
08-13 18:39:47.514 19034-20338/krzosik.mailsenderapp W/System.err:     at krzosik.mailsenderapp.MainActivity$SendMailTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:82)
08-13 18:39:47.515 19034-20338/krzosik.mailsenderapp W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
08-13 18:39:47.515 19034-20338/krzosik.mailsenderapp W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
08-13 18:39:47.515 19034-20338/krzosik.mailsenderapp W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
08-13 18:39:47.515 19034-20338/krzosik.mailsenderapp W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
08-13 18:39:47.516 19034-20338/krzosik.mailsenderapp W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
08-13 18:39:47.516 19034-20338/krzosik.mailsenderapp W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
08-13 18:39:47.516 19034-20338/krzosik.mailsenderapp W/System.err: Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Connection closed by peer
08-13 18:39:48.009 19034-19041/krzosik.mailsenderapp W/art: Suspending all threads took: 199.811ms
08-13 18:39:48.032 19034-20338/krzosik.mailsenderapp W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
08-13 18:39:48.032 19034-20338/krzosik.mailsenderapp W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:318)
08-13 18:39:48.032 19034-20338/krzosik.mailsenderapp W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.waitForHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:623)
08-13 18:39:48.033 19034-20338/krzosik.mailsenderapp W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.getInputStream(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:585)
08-13 18:39:48.033 19034-20338/krzosik.mailsenderapp W/System.err:     at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.initStreams(SMTPTransport.java:1449)
08-13 18:39:48.033 19034-20338/krzosik.mailsenderapp W/System.err:     at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:1336)
08-13 18:39:48.034 19034-20338/krzosik.mailsenderapp W/System.err:  ... 14 more
```

But when i put my app to tablet, everything is ok, mail is send. How can I test this funcionality in emulator with Android Studio, why i get this error? In Eclipse everything is still ok.

Here is my SendMailTask code:

```
private class SendMailTask extends AsyncTask<Message, Void, Void> {
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Please wait", "Sending mail", true, false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Message... messages) {
        try {
            Transport.send(messages[0]);
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The error is caused by line

```
Transport.send(messages[0]);
```

Comment: Wich error do you get? You should of course post the LogCat.

Comment: I edit my question. Now i have another problem with sending emails.

Comment: Please comment onthe exceptions mentioned in the logcat first. Different android versions? You better mention that exception in the subject. And tell which code line causes the exception. Line 100 as is mentioned.

Comment: And catch that exception so your app does not crash.

Comment: Oh i now realise that only emulator gives this exception. Then mention that in the subject too and start your post with it.

Answer (score 0):

1) make sure your android device time is set to current date and time.

2) Make sure your antivirus program isn't interfering and be sure to add an exclusion to your firewall.

3) try this:

```
properties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtp.gmail.com");
```

Comment: Still without success. It is strange, because in Eclipse everything is ok, and problems are with Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use to send emails in Android:

```
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        i.setType("message/rfc822");
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"EMAIL"});
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "SUBJECT");
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "BODY");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
```

Comment: It is not exactly what I want to do. I want to send emails in background, without any interaction with user.